# Receive strange error during mysql auto-repair check optimize

Tags: mysql

I am running the command:

```
/usr/bin/mysqlcheck -hlocalhost -uDATABASE_NAME -pPASSWORD --auto-repair --check --optimize DATABASE_NAME
```

And up until this past week, this command has always run just fine. Last week however, I started receiving the error:

```
Error : Table 'DATABASE_NAME.H1#~i' doesn't exist 
status : Operation failed
```

This is not a table I created or recognize. I have no idea why the error would suddenly start occurring. Has anyone seen this or have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you recently upgrade mysql or switch from a Oracle build to a Percona build or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the original command that you ran

```
/usr/bin/mysqlcheck -hlocalhost -uDATABASE_NAME -pPASSWORD --auto-repair --check --optimize DATABASE_NAME
```

Since you are running [**mysqlchk**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlcheck.html) against the database, you need to specify the `--databases` option

```
/usr/bin/mysqlcheck -hlocalhost -uDATABASE_NAME -pPASSWORD --auto-repair --check --optimize --databases DATABASE_NAME
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: `--databases` is only required when specifying multiple databases in a single command line